# View Switching: Unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: macos, cocoa

I made some example that changes view by clicking button.

When clicking the "fist" button in view, I keep getting the error:

```
[__NSArrayM changeLogView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100539e30
```

Here is the simplified code:

DSWAppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@class DSWHomeViewController;

@interface DSWAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *logBtn;

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTabView *tabView;

@end
```

DSWAppDelegate.m

```
#import "DSWAppDelegate.h"
#import "DSWLogViewController.h"

@implementation DSWAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
// Insert code here to initialize your application
[self.tabView setTabViewType:NSNoTabsNoBorder];

NSTabViewItem *item = nil;

DSWLogViewController *logvc = [[DSWLogViewController alloc initWithNibName:@"DSWLogViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
item = [[NSTabViewItem alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"log"];
[item setView:logvc.view];
[self.tabView insertTabViewItem:item atIndex:0];

}
@end
```

DSWLogViewController.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface DSWLogViewController : NSViewController

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *firstBtn;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSButton *secondBtn;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSBox *box;

- (IBAction)changeLogView:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)testSelector:(id)sender;

@end
```

DSWLogViewController.m

```
#import "DSWLogViewController.h"

@implementation DSWLogViewController

- (IBAction)changeLogView:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"changeLogView : %@", sender);   
}

- (IBAction)testSelector:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"testSelector : %@", sender); 
}
@end
```

And I checked class name of file owner.

[image: file Owner]

Answer (score 0):

Something is sending a `changeLogView:` message to a mutable array instead of your view controller.  Chances are, whatever you've connected the `IBAction` to is pointing to the wrong object - an array of some sort, rather than your view controller.

Comment: The instance of DSWLogViewController - subclass of NSViewController - is not the member variable of delegate. It's just used as local variable in applicationDidFinishLaunching. It seems for the point to occur the error. When declaring variables in header file, it works without the error.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't have a strong reference to the view controller anywhere, so it was being deallocated.  Then the memory where it used to be stored was used to store a mutable array.  If this is the case, the cause is not that you didn't declare it in a header file, it's that your memory management wasn't correct.